# Rectangle in a circle of radius a that maximizes x^n+ y^n

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, implicit-differentiation

> Consider a rectangle with sides $2x$ and $2y$ inscribed in a given fixed circle $$x^2 + y^2 = a^2,$$ and let $n$ be a positive number. We wish to find the rectangle that maximizes the quantity $$z = x^n + y^n.$$ If $n = 2$, it is clear that $z$ has the constant value $a^2$ for all rectangles.
>
> - If $n < 2$, show that the square maximizes $z$; and
> - if $n > 2$, show that $z$ is maximized by a degenerate rectangle in which $x$ or $y$ is $0$.

**My approach.**

$$x^2 + y^2 = a^2$$
$$\therefore\, y = (a^2 - x^2)^{1\over 2}$$

\begin{align}
z &= x^n + y^n \\
{d\over dx}z & = nx^{n-1} - nx(a^2-x^2)^{n-2\over 2}
\end{align}

Equating with $0$ gives:
$$nx^{n-1} = nx(a^2-x^2)^{n-2\over 2}$$

$$x^{n-2} = (a^2 - x^2)^{n-2\over 2}$$

Squaring on both sides gives:

$$(x^2)^{n-2} = (a^2 - x^2)^{n-2}$$

Taking $\ln$ on both sides gives

$$(n-2) \ln(x^2) = (n-2)\ln(a^2 - x^2)$$33

Equating $x^2 = a^2 - x^2$ , we get $x = {a\over \sqrt{2}}$ and $y = {a\over\sqrt{2}}$. In particular $x=y$ implies that the optimal rectange is a square.

My computation appears to be independent of $n$, so I am puzzled about the statement in the question for $n>2$ and $n<2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The stationary point you found could be a minimum point, but also a maximum point, depending on the sign of $n-2$.

Comment: For $n < 2$ your expression for $\frac{dz}{dx}$ is not defined where $y = 0$, so one must check those points separately. Also, between the two equations following, "equating it with $0$...", division by $0$ assumes that $x \neq 0$. The method of Lagrange multipliers might be useful here and can probably be used to avoid the singular behavior of $\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$ at $y = 0$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Yes, and this helped. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TravisWillse Thanks for mentioning about this.  I have now solved the question and posted its answer, you can check it out. Hope you would like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${d\over dx}z$ =
$nx^{n-1}$ - $nx(a^2-x^2)^{n-2\over 2}$

Equating with $0$ gives

$x= {a\over \sqrt {2}}$ so, $y =  {a\over \sqrt {2}}$

and $x= 0$ so, $y = a$

**Now on double differentiating z**

${d^2\over dx^2}z$ = $n(n-1)x^{n-2} - n(a^2 - x^2)^{n-2\over 2} + n(n-2)x^2(a^2 - x^2)^{n-4\over 2}$

**At $x= {a\over \sqrt {2}}$,**

${d^2\over dx^2}z$ simplifies to be $2n(n-2)({a^2\over 2})^{n-2\over 2}$

**So, if $n<2$,**
${d^2\over dx^2}z$ At $x= {a\over \sqrt {2}}$ is < $0$

So, at $x= {a\over \sqrt {2}}$, Z = maximum when $n<2$ and minimum when $n>2$

When $ n < 2$
At $x =0$ ${d^2\over dx^2}z$ is undefined due to the term $n(n-1)x^{n - 2}$ = $n(n-1)$$({1\over 0})^{2 - n}$

**When n>2**

At $x = 0$
${d^2\over dx^2}z$ simplifies to be $-n(a^2)^{n-2\over 2}$ which is $< 0$ as $n > 0$

So $z$ is maximum at $x = 0$

This shows that **when $n<2$** maximum value of $z$ occurs when $x = y = {a\over \sqrt {2}}$ thus a square

**When $n= 2$,** $z$ simply equates to $a^2$

**When n > 2** $z$ is maximum when $x = 0$ , $y = a$ and since $x$ and $y$ are symmetric so they are interchangeable this means z is also maximum when $x = a$ , $y = 0$
and thus it is a **degenerate rectangle** which gives maximum value of $z$ when $n>2$

Answer (score 3):

Alternative way, without calculus.

- If $\,n \le 2\,$ then by the [generalized means inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) $\,\left(\frac{x^n+y^n}{2}\right)^{1/n} \le \left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)^{1/2}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\,$. The maximum is attained when the equality is achieved, for $\,x=y\,$ i.e. the square.
- If $\,n \gt 2\,$ then $\,x^n+y^n=(x^2)^{n/2}+(y^2)^{n/2} \le (x^2+y^2)^{n/2} = a^n\,$ with equality for $\,x=0\,$ or $\,y=0\,$, since $\,x^2/a^2, \,y^2/a^2 \le 1\,$ so $\,(x^2/a^2)^{n/2}+(y^2/a^2)^{n/2} \le x^2/a^2+y^2/a^2 = 1\,$.

Comment: I really liked this way of inequalities used to explain things. Thanks a lot for mentioning this

Comment: This is an especially nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

For $n < 2$ your expression for $\frac{dz}{dx}$ is not defined where $y = 0$, so one must check those points separately. Also, between the two equations following, "equating it with $0$...", division by $0$ assumes that $x \neq 0$.

---

Here's an alternative approach: This problem is a typical candidate for the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), and applying that method has the advantage that it leaves $x$ and $y$ on equal footing and in particular avoid the complications introduced by solving (partially) for $y$ in terms of $x$.

Our objective function is $$f(x, y) := x^n + y^n ,$$ and our constraint is $g(x, y) = 0$, where
$$g(x, y) := x^2 + y^2 - a^2 .$$ (Herein I'll assume $a > 0$, so that the circle is nondegenerate.)

By symmetry we may as well assume that any (constrained, local) extremum $(c, d)$ lies in the closed first quadrant, i.e., are both nonnegative.

> In fact, if $c = 0$, then the constraint implies $d = a$, and vice versa, so if a (constrained, local) extremum occurs where $c = 0$ or $d = 0$, its value is $f(a, 0) = f(0, a) = a^n$, and we may as well restrict the rest of our search to the interior of the first quadrant, i.e., the case $c, d > 0$.

The method of Lagrange multipliers yields that any (constrained, local) extremum $(c, d)$ satisfies $$(\nabla f)(c, d) = \lambda (\nabla g)(c, d) ,$$
that is, the system
\begin{align}
n c^{n - 1} &= 2 c \lambda \\
n d^{n - 1} &= 2 d \lambda .
\end{align}

> Dividing the first equation by the second equation and rearranging yields $c^{n - 2} = d^{n - 2}$, so either (a) $n = 2$ (which corresponds to the tautology that there is a maximum at every point on the unit circle), or (b) the only critical point is $c = d = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$. In the latter case computing gives $f\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = a^n (\sqrt{2})^{2 - n} ,$ and whether this quantity is greater than $f(a, 0) = f(0, a) = a^n$ manifestly depends just on the sign of $2 - n$.